# Plots in python notebook not appearing in gitlab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gitlab, seaborn

I have a bunch of seaborn plots in my python notebook. When I check them into GitLab, they don't appear in the GitLab UI. It just shows `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f28a20abb00>`. 
I use `%matplotlib inline`. Is there anything more I need to do?

Interestingly, if I have a single plot it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the GitLab interface, as reported [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31910) and [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32588). It will be resolved once [this merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/11739) is approved, merged, and released in an upcoming version of GitLab.com.

Comment: A year later and still no fix, apparently :(

Answer (score 1):

Not only this has been fixed (since 2017, five years ago), but those graphs are now visible even in MR (Merge Request)

See [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#rendered-images-in-python-notebook-mrs) (June 2022):

> ### Rendered images in Python notebook MRs
>
> Python notebooks are key to data scientists’ and machine learning engineers’ workflows. These files commonly display charts and graphs via static images to help visualize the notebook.
>
> With this release, we now render these images in the merge request and commit view enabling a better user experience when reviewing code changes including Python notebooks with images.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_1/create-code-review-python-notebook-images.png -- Rendered images in Python notebook MRs]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/jupyter_notebooks/#cleaner-diffs-and-raw-diffs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/88659).